# How can I use the newest version of tsc in Visual studio code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, version

How can I use the newest version of tsc in Visual studio code?

I searched and tried a lot of things I found on the net, but I did not succeed to 
use the newest version of tsc for the internal code checking.

I have VSC 1.41.1 which comes with tsc 3.7.3
For compiling I installed tsc 3.7.5 which gives me some more interesting 
error hints (like TS7053), so I want to use it for internal checking also.
What I expect: the findings of version 3.7.5 are shown 
- in the automatic checks
- in the "problems" tab of the terminal, so I can click them to correct the errors

But whatever I tried, the "problems" tab keeps telling me "No problems..",
the problems are only shown in the "terminal" tab (and are not clickable)

What I have tried:
after several attempts to call "npm install typescript" locally and globally I 
succeeded to get version 3.7.5 offered in the context menu of the installed 
version in the right bottom corner, but choosing it does not give the desired behaviour.

First I tried without defining a project, now I have one - no success

The layout of my project (Project name ZAnim) (subfolder/file is denoted by "--"):

```
.vscode/
--settings.json
node_modules/(tsc installation...)
ZAnim.code-workspace
ZAnim/
--.vscode/
----tasks.json
----tsconfig.json
--*.ts
--package-lock.json
--built/...
--node_modules/(tsc installation...)
```

the file settings.json: (VSCode is the containing folder of the project)

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "c:\\d\\VSCode\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
}
```

the file tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": ".vscode/tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the file tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "target": "ES2017",
        "outFile": "../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "../*.ts"
    ]
}
```

You see, that additionally to the global tsc installation I have 2 local ones here (all 3.7.5), because of
desperation. I also had the file settings.json in the project subfolder, but here 
I always got an error in the "typescript.tsdk" setting: (This setting cannot be applied 
in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly.)

Here is a simple example of some code, that is flagged correctly as wrong with typescript 3.7.5, but not with the internal checking of VSC (although it claims to be using 3.7.5):

```
function errorTS7053(angleList: Array<number>)
{
    var member = angleList[0];
    var nonsense = member[0];
}
```

So my questions:

- is it at all possible to achieve what I want?
- What would be a possible way to achieve this?
- Or might it be possible, that the internal tsc has just a wrong/other configuration?

Comment: Your example generates an error for me with TS 3.7.3. Have you perhaps turned off validation by setting `"typescript.validate.enable": false` or disabled the builtin JS/TS extension?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think, that I did none of the 2 things you mention. I also reinstalled VSCode again - no change. But I have seen one thing: my problem seems to be the setting "noImplicitAny" in tsconfig.json. If I comment it out, I don't see the error any more at compiling. So my question: might it be possible, that the internal checks use some other configuration? I did not find one.